# Email with Evolution

Tags: 11.04, evolution, email, gnupg

Being very new to Ubuntu, which I really like, I now get the following message when I try and send an email:

```
"gpg: skipped "xxxxxx.net": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
", you may need to select different mail options
```

Can anyone help me? I've checked my account set up, and nothing changed. I did install this evening Firewall Configuration and GIMP. Appreciate it. I'm still using version 11.04 by the way.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu! Did you put in the xxxxxxx to protect private information or is that really your server? What is your email provider?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have accidentally configured Evolution to use GPG keys. Have [a look at this article](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_GPG_with_Evolution) - can you confirm that you have the PGP/GPG Key ID field empty in the following window:

[image]

I suspect you may accidentally entered `xxxxxx.net` there

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem

You have two keys, one is `pub` and other is `sub`

```
edward@computer:~$ gpg --edit-key CEF41E5C
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.18; Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

pub  4096R/CEF41E5C  created: 2015-07-27  expires: never       usage: SC  
                     trust: full          validity: unknown
sub  4096R/BB84D566  created: 2015-07-27  expired: 2015-08-26  usage: E   
[ unknown] (1). edward torvalds (encrypt the world) <ltorvalds024@gmail.com>
```

as you can see my  `pub` key is fine but `sub` key is expired
now select `sub` key

```
key 1
```

next

```
expire
```

then enter the time after which it should expire, I choose `0` which means never

```
save
```

Done! :-)